# Searching a python list quickly?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary and a list. The list is made up of values. The dictionary has all of the values plus some more values.

I'm trying to count the number of times the values in the list show up in the dictionary per key/values pair.

It looks something like this:

```
for k in dict:
 count = 0
 for value in dict[k]:
  if value in list:
   count += 1
   list.remove(value)
 dict[k].append(count)
```

I have something like ~1 million entries in the list so searching through each time is ultra slow.

Is there some faster way to do what I'm trying to do?

Thanks,
Rohan

Comment: I'm willing to be this is homework.  It's a really excellent exercise in amortizing the cost of computing all the frequencies in the list prior to doing any lookups of the frequencies.

Comment: You will need to provide a code that you are using:
As this code seems buggy : for k in a: The type of k will depend on type of keys in the dictionary. You are also using list[k] which indicates that there is a constraint on k to be of type int so that it can be an index. Also there is no check for IndexError: list index out of range. Can you be more specific with your code?

Comment: I don't understand what the last line of this code is supposed to be doing.

Comment: What size is the data set you are removing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have all manner of trouble with this code, since you're both removing items from your list and using an index into it.  Also, you're using `list` as a variable name, which gets you into interesting trouble as `list` is also a type.

You should be able to get a huge performance improvement (once you fix the other defects in your code) by using a set instead of a list.  What you lose by using a set is the ordering of the items and the ability to have an item appear in the list more than once.  (Also your items have to be hashable.)  What you gain is O(1) lookup time.

Answer (score 2):

If you search in a list, then convert this list to a set, it will be much faster:

```
listSet = set(list)

for k, values in dict.iteritems():
    count = 0
    for value in values:
        if value in listSet:
            count += 1
            listSet.remove(value)
    dict[k].append(count)

list = [elem for elem in list if elem in listSet]
# return the original list without removed elements
```

Comment: slightly better and more appropriate would be to convert to a set instead of a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

```
for val in my_list:
   if val in my_dict:
      my_dict[val] = my_dict[val] + 1
   else:
      my_dict[val] = 0
```

What you still need

- Handle case when val is not in dict

Answer (score 0):

I changed the last line to append to the dictionary. It's a defaultdict(list). Hopefully that clears up some of the questions. Thanks again.

Comment: Put your edits in question itself, by clicking the `edit` below the tags in your question.